Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename in Next.js
Qs. In Next.js: Cannot rename a folder name
Ans. Simply restart VScode fix this issue
Tried: Npm install and giving permissions by getting and copying prefix in explorer from command prompt but nothing works
Ans. Simply restart VScode fix this issue

Ans. Simply Restarting VSCode fix the renaming issue in next.js app
step: restart VSCode

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
